# Location permission dialog fires before I call requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-location

When my view appears:

```
struct TurnOnLocation: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.orange
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Spacer()

                Button(action: {
                    let locationManager = LocationManager()
                    locationManager.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
                    locationManager.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
                }) {
                    Text("Turn on location")
                }.foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .font(Font.system(size:22))
                .padding(20)
                .background(
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.white)
                        .border(Color.white, width:1)
                )
                .cornerRadius(50)
                .shadow(radius: 10)
                .padding(50)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It asks the user for location before the `Button` is tapped. Why is this? I've added my model below to be fired when it's initialised (which should be when the button is clicked).

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var locationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus? = CLAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined
    @Published var locationPermissionStatus = PermissionStatus.unknown
    @Published var location: CLLocation?
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override init(){
        super.init()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    enum PermissionStatus {
        case unknown
        case authorizedWhenInUse
        case authorizedAlways
        case restricted
        case denied
    }
    
    func getLocation() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D? {
        return self.location?.coordinate
    }
    
}
```

Any idea how I can ensure the dialog only shows after the button is clicked?

**EDIT:**

I have updated the code:

```
Button(action: {
    let locationManager = LocationManager()
    locationManager.requestPermission()
})
```

**Model**

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject , CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @Published var locationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus? = CLAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined
    @Published var locationPermissionStatus = PermissionStatus.unknown
    @Published var location: CLLocation?
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override init(){
        super.init()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }
    
    func requestPermission(){
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                         didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {   switch status {
          case .restricted, .denied:
             // Disable your app's location features
            print("restricted")
             break
                
          case .authorizedWhenInUse:
             // Enable your app's location features.
            print("authorizedWhenInUse")
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
             break
                
          case .authorizedAlways:
             // Enable or prepare your app's location features that can run any time.
            print("authorizedAlways")
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
             break
                
          case .notDetermined:
            print("notDetermined")
             break
       }
    }
```

However, when I click the button, the dialog asking for location permissions disappears after one second. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

There are two things to fix:

1. You're already calling `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` in `init`, which is why you're seeing the alert when the button is constructed. You should remove `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` in `init`.
2. You should call `startUpdatingLocation` after you're sure that you have authorization, in `LocationManager`.

> ```
> func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
>     switch status {
>     case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
>         manager.startUpdatingLocation()
>     default:
>         print("no auth")
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I've have updated my code above in my edit. However, for some reason the dialog asking for location permission disappears after one second. Any idea why?

Comment: My best guess is that it's related with SwiftUI itself. You're creating a manager in a view, and it can be deallocated before finishing its course. You should direct the button's action to an interactor (an `@ObservableObject`, presumably) and allocate the LocationManager in that interactor, where you are sure that it'll stay until you deem it's not necessary anymore. You can try it by implementing the 'deinit' method of your `LocationManager` or have a print in Button's action.

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting authorization in your `LocationManager` init method.
you should remove that code from init.

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var locationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus? = CLAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined
    @Published var locationPermissionStatus = PermissionStatus.unknown
    @Published var location: CLLocation?
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override init(){
        super.init()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func requestAuthorization() {
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    func startUpdate() {
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    enum PermissionStatus {
        case unknown
        case authorizedWhenInUse
        case authorizedAlways
        case restricted
        case denied
    }
    
    func getLocation() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D? {
        return self.location?.coordinate
    }
    
}
```

and in your view:

```
struct TurnOnLocation: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.orange
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Spacer()

                Button(action: {
                    let locationManager = LocationManager()
                    locationManager.requestAuthorization()
                    // you should check for authorization result first
                    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
                }) {
                    Text("Turn on location")
                }.foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .font(Font.system(size:22))
                .padding(20)
                .background(
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.white)
                        .border(Color.white, width:1)
                )
                .cornerRadius(50)
                .shadow(radius: 10)
                .padding(50)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works - but after I click the button, the location dialog disappears after 1 second. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

To fix disappearing after 1 sec, try to init location manage like here:

```
struct TurnOnLocation: View {
    let locationManager = LocationManager() <- try to init location manager here

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.orange
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Spacer()

                Button(action: {   
                 locationManager.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
                    locationManager.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
                }) {
                    Text("Turn on location")
                }.foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .font(Font.system(size:22))
                .padding(20)
                .background(
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.white)
                        .border(Color.white, width:1)
                )
                .cornerRadius(50)
                .shadow(radius: 10)
                .padding(50)
            }
        }
    }
}
```